# Web based form modeler for JBPM

Tags: jbpm, activiti

I am new to JBPM. Is there a web based alternative to the JBPM form [modeler](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-form-modeler)?
I am looking into customizing a web based form modeler for simple user-customizable form applications.

Answer (score 0):

The JBPM Form Modeller is now part of the Business Central Application (formerly Workbench). But it not changed much.

I know that you can change the render engine and provide complete custom UI implementations (e.g angular UI) that leverage the JBPM-Server REST-Endpoints. But in my experience there exists no alternative tooling to do form creation with a WYSIWG behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://bpmn.io/ 
It is a web modeling framework that supports BPMN.
It is the basis for the Camunda web based modeler but can easily be customized for your purposes.

Comment: Well, you can model BPMN diagrams with it. But how does it help me to model data forms?

Comment: @benjist did you find any web-based form modeler for JBPM. I am in a sort of requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: There are lots of web based form modelers, I like form.io and the Bonitasoft UI designer (https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-ui-designer). These can be wired into pretty much any BPM environment. I also like some of the rapid app dev tools like jhipster and Alfresco Application Development Framework. However, these require you create the "application" and then "wire" the BPM engine into the backend services.